# Actionscript 3: Can someone explain to me the concept of static variables and methods?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm learning AS3, and am a bit confused as to what a static variable or method does, or how it differs from a method or variable without this keyword. This should be simple enough to answer, I think.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`static` specifies that a variable, constant or method belongs to the class instead of the instances of the class. `static` variable, function or constant can be accessed without creating an instance of the class i.e `SomeClass.staticVar`. They are not inherited by any subclass and only classes (no interfaces) can have static members.
 A `static` function can not access any non-static members (variables, constants or functions) of the class and you can not use `this` or `super` inside a static function. Here is a simple example.

```
public class SomeClass 
{
  private var s:String;
  public static constant i:Number;
  public static var j:Number = 10;

  public static function getJ():Number 
  {
    return SomeClass.j;
  }
  public static function getSomeString():String 
  {
    return "someString";
  }
}
```

In the TestStatic, static variables and functions can be accessed without creating an instance of SomeClass.

```
public class TestStaic 
{
  public function TestStaic():void 
  {
    trace(SomeClass.j);  // prints 10
    trace(SomeClass.getSomeString());  //prints "someString"
    SomeClass.j++; 
    trace(SomeClass.j);  //prints 11
  }
}
```

Comment: The last line doesn't print 11, only sets j to 11 :P

Comment: A good scenario where you would use a static variable/function is if you are generating a unique id for an instance of a class. Since the variable belongs to the class you can call a static method (that would increment the counter) and then assign it to the instance of the class (most likely in the constructor). Thats how I first learnt about them :)

Comment: And very common use of static keyword is in 'Singleton Design Pattern'. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 13):

A static variable or method is shared by all instances of a class. That's a pretty decent definition, but may not actually make it as clear as an example...

So in a class `Foo` maybe you'd want to have a static variable `fooCounter` to keep track of how many `Foo`'s have been instantiated. (We'll just ignore thread safety for now).

```
public class Foo {
    private static var fooCounter:int = 0;

    public function Foo() {
        super();
        fooCounter++;
    }

    public static function howManyFoos():int {
        return fooCounter;
    }
}
```

So each time that you make a `new Foo()` in the above example, the counter gets incremented.  So at any time if we want to know how many `Foo`'s there are, we don't ask an instance for the value of the counter, we ask the `Foo` class since that information is "static" and applies to the entire`Foo` class.

```
var one:Foo = new Foo();
var two:Foo = new Foo();
trace("we have this many Foos: " + Foo.howManyFoos());  // should return 2
```

Comment: Flash has no threading issues due to its single-threaded model.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is static functions could only access static variables, and couldn't be override, see "[hidden](http://blog.sanaulla.info/2008/02/29/overriding-vs-hiding/)".