# Access a variable in a class trough another class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, variables

Noob question (probably). I have a class with a `var textFieldObjets:Textfield`
in my class **environnement**

What i'd like to do, is access this var from another class and change the text. I tried things like `environnement.textFieldObjets.text = "blabla";` Got error 1119, Access of a possible undefined property textFieldObjets trough a reference with static type Class. I can't even access my environnement class...

How could I do that? thx!

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo, but usually, in Flex/AS3 coding conventions, class names should start with an uppercase letter (Environnement). You can read more about these coding conventions here : http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions#CodingConventions-Classnames

Comment: Hahaha true! My bad, not a typo, just something I didn't learn to do at the beginning of my training. I'll keep that in mind for future coding. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the variable a class member with `public static` identifier.

```
public static var textFieldObjects:Textfield;
```

For more information on what `static` and `public` keywords mean, you could refer to this question: [Actionscript 3: Can someone explain to me the concept of static variables and methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738349/actionscript-3-can-someone-explain-to-me-the-concept-of-static-variables-and-met)

Documentation from Adobe: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f30.html

Comment: ohhh so the static does the magic! I tought you only had to put it public to be able to view it! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You need to declare the variable as "public":

```
public var textFieldObjects:TextField;
```

**2.**  You can't access a regular property directly through the *class*--you need an *instance* of your `environnement` class.  If you're working in the Flash tool, you'll need to place your component on the stage (this creates the instance), and then give it an instance id.  Then you can use that id to access the component from your actionscript.

So if you call your instance: myEnv, then your actionscript might look like this:

```
myEnv.textFieldObjets.text = "blabla";
```

If you're working in flex, then it works the same way -- just place the component into your mxml document, and set it's `id` attribute to a unique name.  Now, you can access that component from script, by using the id you defined.