# Passing Variable from an Instance of one Class to an Instance of Another?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, game-engine

I'm using AS3 to create a little 2D game in FlashPunk with a friend. I want my level to pass a couple positions to my player, but don't know how to do it. The both have instances created of them in GameWorld `

```
public class GameWorld extends World {

    public function GameWorld() {
        add(new Level);
        add(new Player);
    }

}
```

Which has it's instance created here: `FP.world = new GameWorld;`

How can I get some variables from the level to player? They are both only created once.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395898/access-a-variable-in-a-class-trough-another-class?rq=1 may answer your question for you

Answer (score 0):

You can declare Player as a public variable in GameWorld class:

```
public class GameWorld extends World {

    public var player:Player;

    public function GameWorld() {
        add( new Level() );

        player = new Player();
        add( player );
    }
}
```

Then inside the Level class you can access Player by doing:

```
world.player
```